# Is it possible to push browser notifications from a rails app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, browser, notifications, push-notification

I'm wondering if there's some way to push browser notifications from a Rails app using a gem of some kind I've been doing a lot of googling about this and can't seem to find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com)-ing not happening here either.

The current answer is there doesn't seem to be a simple answer.  There's often a client-side (js) subscription UX *and* a backend of some sort which can send pushes to the browser (because the browser does the polling for notifications to various PN providers user has subscribed to, which may vary by browser PN api) even when the user is not visiting the website.  To see it in action, browse from a modern Chrome to [CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/)*, subscribe, close the CNN tab but leave the browser open to see a PN when a news story lands.  You may opt for [Pusher](https://pusher.com/docs/device_compatibility), <s>[ZeroPush](https://zeropush.com/)</s> (acquired by Twitter and folding into [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/))  or <s>[Roost](https://goroost.com/browser-push)</s> (none of Roost's demos work on OS X on any popular browser with zero extensions and a crazy fast internet connection) if there's coin to drop to get going sooner.

**Note for Chrome:** There appears to be at least **two (2)** PN APIs, the older *Chrome Extension Push* which is being deprecated and *Chrome Web Push*, which can forward PNs to the OS *which works off-page*.    Not sure if CEP works without being on a PN-enabled page... or the current state of PN in other browsers like FF ([webpush](https://webpush-wg.github.io/webpush-protocol/)), Safari, IE/Edge or mobile browsers.

This also seems like fertile ground for someone awesome to contribute an errbit-like Rails app/gem.  By looking at [push-api](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/) and/or sniffing your traffic, it might be possible to reenigne a somewhat simple and robust lightweight server for self-hosting (say using Sinatra, Node or Go) that works for most major browsers.

**Yes, same the news org which [closed](http://uproxx.com/media/daily-show-cnn/) its investigative journalism unit to focus on "hotel" and "talking-head" "journalism".  See [VICE](https://news.vice.com/) (where [Kaj Larsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaj_Larsen) works now), [Channel4](http://www.channel4.com/news/) and [Journeyman Pictures](http://www.journeyman.tv/) for alternatives.*

Btw, for related *mobile app (not mobile browser)* PNs: have look at [`ruby-push-notifications`](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-push-notifications)... most ecosystems require installing an official app in order to use their PN systems.

### Chrome + OS X PN

[image: screenshot of chrome notification on osx presented by Notification Center]

Answer (score 0):

Rails is server side. To be able to do this you need something in the javascript you're sending back to the client to do the job for you.

the way I would do this is have something on the client, in javascript, that goes back to the server - in an async manner - and checks to see if there are any notifications to display.